# Extracting sheets to seprate files / variable sheet names / loop

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I have a Spreadsheet with around 60 sheets, every week they are the same + sometimes there is a new sheet.

I am trying to make macro that would export sheets to a separate file specified in Excel file. 
Colum C contains sheet names and column E contains file path.

This is the code I have made so far and I struggle to use variable sheet name from cell and saving files

```
Sub SavingweekEnd()
    Dim ABC As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ChDir _
    "S:\    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "S:\BD1.xls"
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast

    x = 5
    For x = 5 To Range("h1").Value

    ABC = Cells(x, 3).Value

    Sheets(ABC).Select
    Sheets(ABC).Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Cells(x, 5).Value, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

    Next x

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell objects are not fully qualified, so they will always refer to the `ActiveSheet` and the `ActiveSheet` many not be the sheet you may want to work with. It may not even be in the workbook you are expecting it to be in.

Is this what you are trying?

**My Assumptions**

1. `Range("H1").Value` has a valid number
2. `Cells(i, 3).Value` has a valid sheet name
3. Column E has full filepath and names. If not, then amend `thisws.Cells(i, 5).Value` accordingly

**Untested**

```
Sub SavingMonthEndCostsheetsSJPUT()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim thisws As Worksheet
    Dim ShtName As String

    Dim i As Long

    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set thisws = thisWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 5 To thisws.Range("H1").Value
        ShtName = thisws.Cells(i, 3).Value

        thisWB.Sheets(ShtName).Copy

        Set thatWb = ActiveWorkbook

        thatWb.SaveAs Filename:=thisws.Cells(i, 5).Value, FileFormat:=xlNormal

        DoEvents

        thatWb.Close (False)

        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub
```